# Solr function query filter improvementss

Tags: solr

I'm trying to filter documents based on all values in a field.
For this I had used a function query in a filterquery.

To explain it.
I have exclusion rules on regions and on countries.
Each document contains the values for which it is excluded.

If exclusion rules exist on regions, do nothing.(the region filter query is a separate one)
If exclusion rules don't exist for region, use the country.

For this requirement I had the filter query below.

```
fq="!{!df=excluded_region v=$user.region}"      
fq={!frange l=0 u=0}and(not(docfreq(excluded_region,$user.region)),termfreq(excluded_country,$user.country))
```

It works fine except when a region is deleted from the index entirely.(none of the documents still have that value)
The docFrequency is not changed.
I know I could resolve this by segment merging, but this is not possible due to the size of the index.
Also possible by dynamically adding filter statements, but I'd prefer to have these blocking rules in the appends section of the request handlers.

Is there a better way to write this function query?
Is it possible to do a subquery across all documents to check whether a region exists?

Example(s) of how the data is supposed to work:

| DocId | excluded_region | excluded_country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Doc A | A1 | BE |
| Doc B | A2 | BE |
| Doc C | A3,A1 | BE |
| Doc D | A3,A1,A4 | BE |

If for example the user has country BE and region A5(not existing in any document), nothing is returned.

If he has region A1, document B is the only returned document.

Comment: Currently solved it by adding all excluded_regions to each document and use the termfreq of that field. However this means that always all documents need to be indexed everyday with all excluded_regions in a field. Was hoping for a more dynamic solution.

Comment: you can use join, but it have limitation.